# ID as int in neo4j bulk import produces error in relationships import

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I use the admin-import tool of Neo4j to import bulk data in csv format. I use Integer as ID datatype in the header [journal:ID:int(Journal-ID)] and the part of importing the nodes works fine. When the import-tool comes to the relationships, I get the error that the referring node is missing. 
Seems like the relations-import it is searching the ID in String format. 
I already tried to change the type of the ID in the relations File as well, but get an other error. I found no way to specify the ID as int in the relations-File.

Here is an minimal example. Lets say we have two node types with the headers:

```
journal:ID:int(Journal-ID)
```

and

```
documentID:ID(Document-ID),title
```

and the example files journal.csv:

```
"123"
"987"
```

and document.csv:

```
"PMID:1", "Title"
"PMID:2", "Other Title"
```

We also have a relation "hasDocument" with the header:

```
:START_ID(Journal-ID),:END_ID(Document-ID)
```

and the example file relation.csv:

```
"123", "PMID:1"
```

When running the import I get the the error:

```
Error in input data
Caused by:123 (Journal-ID)-[hasDocument]->PMID:1 (Document-ID) referring to missing node 123
```

I tried to specify the relation header as

```
:START_ID:int(Journal-ID),:END_ID(Document-ID)
```

but this also produces an error.

The command to start the import is:

`neo4j-admin import --nodes:Document="document-header.csv,documentNodes.csv" --nodes:Journal="journal-header.csv,journalNodes.csv" --relationships:hasDocument="hasDocument-header.csv,relationsHasDocument.csv"`

Is there a way to specify the ID in the relation file as Integer or is there an other solution to that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be supported. The documentation doesn't mention it and the code doesn't have [such test case](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/search?p=1&q=START_ID&unscoped_q=START_ID).

You could import the data with String ids and cast it after you start the database.

```
MATCH (j:Journal)
SET j.id = toInteger(j.id)
```

If your dataset is large you can use `apoc` with iterate:

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate("
MATCH (j:Journal) RETURN j
","
SET j.id = toInteger(j.id)
",{batchSize:10000})
```